# All document classes gone in LyX

Tags: lyx, document-classes

I have somehow managed to lose all my document classes and hence cannot compile anything. I  have tried re-configuring and re-installing to no avail. I am on a university computer and cannot edit the program files.

Comment: Have thought of contacting your support staff?

Answer (score 2):

Follow the [link](http://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/Troubleshooting). I had the same problem and I configured the lyx by running the configure.py file in  the lyx resources folder. If the configure.py doesn't work then change the properties of the lyx folder to be accessible if you are not the administrator and then reconfigure again. During the configuration the luatex may take a lot of memory--see the task manager--but it is not a problem. Just leave until everything is done. Then instead of copying the four files in the resources as suggested in the above link copy everything in the resources folder to the lyx folder in the C:\users\%you%\appdata\Local\lyx??? depending on the version of lyx you are using.